# how to save radio buttons values in db in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

forms.py

```
Date_Format = (
    ('0', ' dd / mm / yyyy'),
    ('1', 'mm / dd / yyyy'),
)

Time_Format = (
    ('0', ' 12 hour AM / PM '),
    ('1', ' 24 hour '),
)

class DateFormatForm(Form):
    date_format = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Date_Format,widget=forms.RadioSelect())

class TimeFormatForm(Form):
    time_format = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Time_Format,widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

models.py

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_format = models.CharField('Date format', max_length=100)
    time_format = models.CharField('Time format', max_length=100)
```

1. I had kept the two forms namely,DateFormatForm and TimeFormatForm in template for selecting the date ad time formats.
2. In models their are two field namely, i.date_format and ii.time_format for which  forms choices are created.So if the user clicks this format  ('0', ' dd / mm / yyyy'), and press save,the corresponding value is "0" which should be saved in date_format.

3.So date formats are saved in their appropriate fields with "0"'s or "1".

I can't use forms form validation and save because i am not using modelsForm,So how to save it in database.

Please share me a slight idea to perform this with out form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your model could be refactored and you should use Django ModelForm.

But, why do you want to save the human-readable part in db if you have hardcored them in your code? do you want get it after?

if you want to get the human-readable part, just use `get_date_format_display()` for DateFormat model and `get_time_format_display()` for TimeFormat model. Django generates these methods

see this [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Hope this helpsvalue